# Can't pass $this as an argument to an object constructor

Tags: php

I am trying to create a new object and pass the creator as a parameter in the constructor.

```
    public function update_user_score(&$response){
      $user_id          = $_POST['user_id'];
      $score_details        = $_POST['score_details'];
      require_once 'Score_manager.php';
      $score_manager = new Score_manager($this);
      $score_manager->update_user_score($user_id, $score_details);
      $response['success']  = 1;
      $response['new_score']    = $new_score;
      return;
    }
```

and in the Score_manager the constructor is :

```
// constructor
function __construct($mfunc_helper) {
    require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
    // connecting to database
    $this->db = new DB_Connect();
    $this->db->connect();
    $this->$func_helper = $mfunc_helper;
}
```

once I get tto the line $this->$func_helper = $mfunc_helper; I get the next error "Undefined variable: func_helper ...". I tried to pass $this with & but I got "Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed ...". What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->$func_helper` should be `$this->func_helper`. You don't need the extra `$` in front of property names. I personally think this is very inconsistent syntax, but it is how it is. :(

The error you are getting, is because PHP is searching for a local variable named `$func_helper`. It wants to use the value of that variable to find a property name of `$this`. So actually you're not yet writing the property but reading the local variable, which doesn't exist. therefor, you get this error.

Comment: And &$this should never be needed after PHP4.

Answer (score 1):

You have to access class property using `$this->func_helper` not $this->$func_helper. But your `"Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed"` error occurs in different situation.